# Why is this upstart script not stopping my process?

Tags: upstart

I am trying to write an upstart script that checks if my process is running by pinging it's HTTP interface. So far, I just can't get the `post-start` clause to work. Here's a simplified version that I've tried:

```
description "my application"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
respawn limit 360 180
setuid myuser
setgid mygroup

chdir /my/directory
exec /bin/sleep 60

post-start script
  sleep 5
  stop
  exit 1
end script
```

From terminal:

```
/etc/init$ sudo start myapp   # returns after 5 seconds
myapp start/running, process 27477
jrantil@myserver:/etc/init$ ps -ef|grep sleep
107      27477     1  0 16:56 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sleep 60
jrantil  27482 26900  0 16:56 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
```

Could anyone tell me why my application is not shutting down after 5 seconds? As far as I've understood, if I don't call `stop` it will simply respawn.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make this a [task script](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#task), not a service script. That means that the Upstart init daemon will not expect it to remain running, and will not attempt to restart it or track the PID. Replace the `stop`, `exec`, and `post-start` stanzas with a `task` directive, leaving something like this:

```
description "my application"

start on runlevel [2345]
task

setuid myuser
setgid mygroup

chdir /my/directory
exec /bin/sleep 5
```

Obviously, replace the `exec` line with something meaningful for you. Perhaps you want a `script` to run a few commands in a row. If instead your process never stops by itself, and you want Upstart to kill it after 5 seconds, try this:

```
description "my application"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on kill-me-please

setuid myuser
setgid mygroup

chdir /my/directory
exec /bin/sleep 60

post-start script
    /bin/sleep 5
    initctl emit kill-me-please
end script
```

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific; my main process is asctually a long running java process, to I don't think `task` is the right way to go. Also, I tried your second example and it seems to block forever.